# Switch of react router dom doesn't work if I put in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm learning react and I try to switch between my pages with react-router-dom.

I have a component Menu with my links and I call this component into my App component but it doesn't work. But if a put my links directly into my App component it works well.

And also, it doesn't work if I leave `to="/"` but i put somethig else like `to="/home"` for the first link.

```
const Menu = () => {
  const padding = {
    paddingRight: 5
  }
  return (
    <Router>
        <Link style={padding} to="/">anecdotes</Link>
        <Link style={padding} to="/create">create new</Link>
        <Link style={padding} to="/about">about</Link>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

And a component App.js that return my routes

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Software anecdotes</h1>
      <Menu />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/s">
              <AnecdoteList anecdotes={anecdotes} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/create">
              <CreateNew addNew={addNew} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
              <About />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Router` from your `main` component then it'll work fine.